# Объясните, пожалуйста, сужение и расширение типов (не примитив)

Tags: java

Плохо понимаю вот такие конструкции

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Object obj = new Tiger();
  Animal animal = (Animal) obj;
  Cat cat = (Cat) obj;
  Tiger tiger = (Tiger) animal;
  Tiger tiger2 = (Tiger) cat;
}
```

Comment: Какая строчка Вам непонятна?

Comment: По идее, все строчки. Так как я не понимаю нормально, что они значат. Но можно объяснить хотя бы на 2ух первых

Answer (score 3):

`Object obj = new Tiger();` поскольку все объектные типы унаследованы от Object, вы всегда можете использовать такую конструкцию, но на практике мало встречается.

`Animal animal = (Animal) obj;` явное приведение типа, используется довольно часто - например у вас есть Map, вы знаете, что под определенным ключом у вас находится объект типа Animal, и хотите использовать его методы для обработки, тогда вы и выполняете яное приведение типа (Animal)obj. Перед явным приведением типа, чтоб избежать ошибки, выполняют проверку какого типа объект, выглядит это так

```
 if( obj instanceof Animal ){
     Animal animal = (Animal)obj;
 }
```

но это сработает только если ваш объект является непосредственно экземпляром класса Animal. Если ваш объект например Cat extends Animal, то проверка instanceof даст вам false. Тогда надо использовать другой способ проверки

```
 if( Animal.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass()) ){
     Animal animal = (Animal)obj;
 }
```

Comment: главное на ошибку кастинга не наткнуться

Comment: `instanceof` проверяет, является ли экземпляр `obj` объектом _того же класса или **подкласса**_ (`obj` is `Tiger` -> `obj instanceof Animal -> true`).  `Class::isAssignableFrom` проверяет, можно ли присвоить ссылке с классом _слева_ объект с классом _справа_, т.е. является ли класс _слева_ таким же или _суперклассом_ класса справа (`Animal superclass of Tiger -> true`, но наоборот).